# how can I search data only in column between ID's a to b

Tags: php, mssql-jdbc

How can I search data only in column between ID's a to b.
I'm using the following statement but it seems the search runs at the entire table

```
$statement = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  mylist 
            where `categ` between 300 and 399
            &&   `name` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%'
            ||  `street` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%'
            ||  `description` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%'
                    ORDER BY id");
```

Comment: you need to group your OR conditions between brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You may use another Constraint like **greater than and/or lesser  than**:

```
        $statement = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  mylist ML
        WHERE (ML.categ>=300 AND ML.categ<=399)
        &&   `name` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%'
        ||  `street` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%'
        ||  `description` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%'
                ORDER BY id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your condition like this,

```
$statement = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `mylist` 
        where `categ` between (300 and 399)
        &&   (`name` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%'
        ||  `street` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%'
        ||  `description` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%')
                ORDER BY id");
```

Comment: @user1377921 : If you problem solved you can mark accepted to any appropriate ans and also make up votes ;)